# Text-to-speech engine with different voices for Android

Tags: gratis, android, speech-synthesis

Besides the default Google one and Pico, are there any other good/free TTS engines for Android?

I would like to have different voices available - I have heard tons of options on traditional GPS devices (even Yoda!), but I don't see any equivalent for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [Ivona](http://www.ivona.com/) a try. It has a **lot** of voices available. The [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts) has less voices but also available in many languages. Other voices will probably be ported to Android over time.

It is free while in beta, which is over a year now. I've used it ever since and had no problems despite the beta status.

Note that besides the TTS engine you have to also [install specific voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=IVONA%20Text-to-Speech).